# Why don't date functions work as defaults in MS Access used with MySQL

Tags: mysql, ms-access-2010

I am converting a Large MS Access 2010 application to act as a front end to MySQL 5.5 database, via the v5.1 ODBC Connector, and I am experiencing a strange problem when inserting new records with bound data forms.

In a data-entry form, if the default value of a date field is set in the properties of the control as a constant (such as #04-01-2014#) the new record is created in MySQL successfully, and after saving, all fields are visible in their associated bound fields.  But if the default value is defined in the Access control as a *function* (example: =Date()) then although the MySQL row is created successfully, ODBC fails to find the new row and Access displays all values as #DELETED. Refresh and/or requery commands are not helpful. This is nothing to do with the well known issue of -- must have a primary key and a datestamp in MySQL.  All of these safeguards are in place, and as stated, it does work without FE defaults.

No defaults are being set in the MySQL backend, and it makes no difference whether or not Nulls are allowed. Data type used in the backend is DateTime. If I do set defaults in the BE and none in the FE, everything is fine. But that way, the user DOES NOT SEE THE DEFAULTS in the data entry form... an unacceptable situation.

I have also tested both ODBC v5.2, and MySQL 5.6 with exactly the same results.

A solution that seems to work (so far)  is to set all defaults in code, in the form.beforeUpdate event.  Something like this:

```
form_beforeUpdate()
   if me.newrecord then
      field1.value = date()
      field2.value = fOtherDate()
      'etc
   end if   
   'other code
exit sub
```

I could insert all new records with unbound forms and passthrough queries.  But with 75,000 lines of code, that is a very big job

My question is - why do I need these "workarounds"?  Isn't the whole purpose of ODBC to allow fairly normal operation? What is it about simple functions that "breaks it"?  What other "ordinary" Access methods will break it? If I don't understand why it didn't work I can't be sure it is properly fixed.

Has anyone else had any experience with this SPECIFIC issue? I could not find any reference to it elsewhere. Thank you for your time.

Comment: tl;dr. It would be extremely helpful if you could condense this down to a more clearly stated question. (The proper solution is to configure the MySQL database to provide the default values, and overwrite them as needed in your INSERT statements from your app. That's specifically how database servers are supposed to be used - let them enforce constraints or provide default values instead of trying to do it in your front end application.)

Comment: I just tried to recreate your issue but I could not. The MySQL table has a DATETIME column named `DateAdded`. The Access linked table treats it as a Date/Time field. The data-entry form uses `=Date()` for the default value and new records are added correctly, without displaying `#Deleted`. Tested on a 32-bit machine using Access 2010, MySQL 5.6.13, and MySQL Connector ODBC 5.2

Comment: Thanks. Kind of you to do a test and report your results.

Comment: Have not seen your form, but just FYI I also could make it work every time, if I used a very basic form, such as the one the Access wizards create automatically. But when the form starts to get more complex it starts to get less reliable and less predictable. Many times I thought I had solved it, only to come in next day and find it had stopped working. After 2 weeks of trying I gave up and changed to passthrough inserts.